# session_start() and No input file specified error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a php file index.php and bagıslarım.php with its drowdown menu.  When I want to go bagıslarım.php it displays an error

> No input file specified error.

When webpage get busy, it does not work. and phpstorm editor get this error ! How can I solve this error ?

> HP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers
>   already sent by (output started at
>   /var/www/html/Bagis/bagıslarım.php:17) in
>   /var/www/html/Bagis/loggedin.php on line 3
>
> PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter -
>   headers already sent (output started at
>   /var/www/html/Bagis/bagıslarım.php:17) in
>   /var/www/html/Bagis/loggedin.php on line 3
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER in
>   /var/www/html/Bagis/loggedin.php on line 5
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: username in
>   /var/www/html/Bagis/loggedin.php on line 22
>
> PHP Warning:  mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result
>   index 8 in /var/www/html/Bagis/loggedin.php on line 28

bagıslarım.php :

```
<?php
            require 'connect.inc.php';
            require ('loggedin.php');

             $userid=getusersfield('id');

            echo $userid;

            ?>
```

Comment: You have any output before `session_start()` function.

Comment: i have only ob_start() code . i have any output

Comment: Evidently you have. Warning message is clear.

Comment: http://localhost/Bagis/bag%C4%B1slar%C4%B1m.php is working but http://localhost:63342/html/Bagis/bag%C4%B1slar%C4%B1m.php is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send anything to the response before executing `session_start()`. Go to connect.inc.php and move `session_start()` to a place where nothing have been sent yet.

Comment: session_start() is not in connect.inc.php it locates in loggedin.php .

Comment: Wherever it is, just make sure that the line is above any output.

Comment: http://localhost/Bagis/bag%C4%B1slar%C4%B1m.php is working but http://localhost:63342/html/Bagis/bag%C4%B1slar%C4%B1m.php is not working